# Consulta com Datetime Sql e C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net

Estou tentando fazer com que devolva para mim o paciente de um determinado dia e hora no comando a seguir:

```
SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT P.nome,P.codPaciente, 
M.codMedico, C.descricao from Consulta as C " +
", Medico as M, Paciente as P where M.codMedico = C.codMedico and " +
"P.codPaciente = C.codPaciente and M.cpf = @cpf and " +
"cast(C.dataConsulta as date) = @data",conexao);
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", Session["cpf"]);
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", data);
```

Mas está devolvendo todos os pacientes do dia.

Tentei mudar `as date` para `as datetime`, quando faço isso ele devolve `null`, tentei converter em `datetime` a data e passar direto mas não vai.

A data está sendo passada dessa forma: `2018-11-10 17:35`.

Mudei ela para ser `2018-11-10 17:35:00.000`, mas mesmo assim não foi.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Se o tipo do campo for DateTime então remova o cast. ex: `C.dataConsulta=@data`

Comment: a coluna dataConsulta é de que tipo?

Comment: Oie William,se eu removo  o cast ele não vai,tentei fazer isso mudando também o valor passado no @data para datetime.mas não foi.

Comment: o dataConsulta é dateTime

Comment: ao meu ver então você não deveria dar cast pra date nele então já que você precisa do horario e isso vai fazer você perder a informação, o data é uma string ou um datetime?

Comment: Como está declarado o parâmetro @data? Se ele estiver como string, sugiro que utilize 
``"C.dataConsulta = convert(datetime, @data, 120)",conexao);``

Answer (score 4):

Se você quer consultar data e horário, não pode fazer um *cast* para o tipo `date` porque esse tipo não tem informação de horário, apenas de data. Eu imagino que o seu campo `Consulta.dataConsulta` esteja definido com o tipo `datetime` no banco de dados, então também não precisaria fazer um *cast* para esse tipo.

Você disse que a data-hora sendo pesquisada é `2018-11-10 17:35`, e que tentou também o formato `2018-11-10 17:35:00.000`. Esse segundo formato seria o mais correto para uma pesquisa em campo do tipo `datetime` ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql)), mas, note que em ambos casos você está informando apenas as partes das **horas** e dos **minutos**, mas os **segundos** e **milissegundos** estão zerados. Ou seja, se a consulta tiver sido gravada no banco como `2018-11-10 17:35:17.003`, você não a encontrará.

Se você quer encontrar uma consulta às `17:35` você provavelmente terá que consultar os horários entre `17:35:00.000` e `17:35:59.999`, e o código pode ser assim:

```
DateTime dtIni = new DateTime(data.Year, data.Month, data.Day, data.Hour, data.Minute, 0, 0);
DateTime dtFim = new DateTime(data.Year, data.Month, data.Day, data.Hour, data.Minute, 59, 999);

SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand(
   "SELECT DISTINCT P.nome, P.codPaciente, M.codMedico, C.descricao" +
   " FROM Consulta AS C, Medico AS M, Paciente AS P" +
   " WHERE M.codMedico = C.codMedico" +
   " AND P.codPaciente = C.codPaciente" +
   " AND M.cpf = @cpf" +
   " AND C.dataConsulta BETWEEN @dataHoraIni AND @dataHoraFim",
   conexao);

cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", Session["cpf"]);
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataHoraIni", dtIni);
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataHoraFim", dtFim);
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma informação que talvez seja relevante e informativa ao mesmo tempo neste caso.

Como já foi falado acima pelo colega @Pedro Gaspar, Date é diferente de Datetime.
No banco de dados SQL Server, sempre que se registra uma data sem hora/minuto/segundos/milissegundos, essa data vai se comportar em modo de comparação de valores sempre como se fosse apenas a dia/mês/ano, se por ventura algum dia houver o registro de data com  hora/minuto/segundos/milissegundos, a comparação de datas será feita por inteiro e irá contemplar todos os valores do campo.

Se for o caso de apenas comparar as datas e não seu range de tempo percorrido (hh:mm:ss), seria interessante fazer um cast no campo para trazer apenas dd/mm/yyyy.